# How to get data using foreign key in eloquent model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have model named 'PropertyLead' as,

```
class PropertyLead extends Model
{

 public function leadPropertyDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Property\Property', 'Property_id','id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Access\User\User','user_id','id');
    }

     public function propertyRatings()
    {
     return $this
      ->hasMany('App\Models\Property\PropertyRating','Property_id','Property_id');
    }
}
```

In my controller I am trying to get data as ,

```
$leads = PropertyLead::with('leadPropertyDetails','user','propertyRatings')
                        ->get();
```

Here in $leads variable i am getting all the data that I want but In 'propertyRatings' I am getting user_id and other details. I also want to get the name user who rated that property using that user_id in propertyRatings object. I am really troubled in this query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nested eager loading syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load nested relationships:

```
PropertyLead::with('propertyRatings', 'propertyRatings.user', 'leadPropertyDetails', 'user')->get();
```

Then you be able to display user name with:

```
@foreach ($leads as $lead)
    @foreach ($lead->propertyRatings as $propertyRating)
        {{ $propertyRatings->user->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hey when I did like above, I am getting other relation objects of user as well ...I tried with calling function using $query and selecting only name... but still it returns me name only with user relations... am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: $leads = PropertyLead::with(['user','propertyRatings','propertyRatings.user' => function ($query) {
           $query->select(['name']);}]) ->where('brokarage_id','=',$input)->get();

Comment: Thank you. The problem with your query is in `select()`. Just add foreign key to the array to make relationship work `$query->select(['name', 'user_id']);`